# Confusion about Unicode and the number of bits needed to represent a character

Tags: unicode

I am confused on the fact that there are 1,114,112 characters in Unicode, but at the same time we can use UTF-16 (which uses 16 bits) to access all of the characters. I mean, wouldn't they require 32 bit to be stored?

I have heard it has to do with surrogate pairs, but I have no idea what they actually are.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) first. Then ask again if any questions remain.

Comment: nice article. but still i wont understand the myth of storing char in Unicode in two parts? upper and lower?

Comment: if u can please explain with an example, tht would be handy.
if a chinees CHAR (any one) is there to be stored how will it be stored?

Comment: It can be stored in a number of ways. Take , the Phoenician letter teth, for example - it's beyond the basic multilingual plane, so it can't be stored in two bytes. In UTF-8, it's four bytes: `f0 90 a4 88`. In UTF-16, it's stored as a surrogate pair - two consecutive two-byte code units representing one code point: `02 d8 08 dd`. UTF-32 can store it as a single four-byte code unit: `08 09 01 00`.

Comment: Tim, I found Joel's article quite lacking in some respects, actually. It may make some basic concepts clear, but Unicode is way too complex to summarise it in such a short article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different encodings for unicode. Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 use one or several 8 or 16-bit blobs to represent a single character depending any unicode code point.

wchar_t or 16-bit integer on the other hand can only represent some unicode code points.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings

about surrogate pairs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k5611at.aspx
http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-4

Answer (score 2):

Unicode was historically a 16-bit code and character set (in the very first versions). That's also when UCS-2 was created as an encoding, where each character from the Universal character set was a 2-byte unit.

It quickly became clear (also due to some scope changes of the project) that 16 bits and thus 65536 characters are too few to work with and Unicode was expanded to 21 bits, organised in 17 *planes* of which the first 65536 character form the 0th, the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP).

At the same time 2048 code points in the BMP were set aside as so-called high and low surrogates. Two of which then would represent a character in another plane. That enabled UTF-16, where each code *unit* is still two bytes long and one or two code units (in the latter case by combining a high and low surrogate) would represent a single code *point*. Likewise, it was declared that those surrogates may not appear in isolation or wrong order. Surrogate characters are mainly an oddity (They form the largest block of non-characters in Unicode) but were technically the cleanest way of enabling a path from 16-bit to 21-bit Unicode.

Whatever you may hear or think, Unicode hasn't been a 16-bit code for the longest time of its history and currently there is nothing that requires any 16-bit-ness. However:

1. Systems and environments that were very early adopters of Unicode initially used UCS-2, simply because that was an easy way of supporting all characters from the new character set. Those transitioned to UTF-16. Windows, Java and .NET (due to its Windows heritage) are examples of this.
2. Most other places use UTF-8 nowadays, which is also the dominant encoding on the web (according to Google). UTF-8 doesn't need surrograte pairs but instead employs a different scheme where code points are represented by one (ASCII), two, three or four code units (depending on the code point).
3. There is also UTF-32, identical with UCS-4, using four bytes per character. This is mainly used for some internal processes of software where each code point needs to have the same length. It is rarely used in storage or interchange.

Comment: Ask another question please. And ask it in a useful way that can be answered.

Comment: Dude you should be writing for wikipedia!

Comment: Nah, I can't really produce a coherent text from my knowledge. It's much easier answering questions. Besides, I'm only a lurker on the Unicode mailing list and many people there know much more than me (if above information is even correct).